# Rails: Tight coupling between deeply nested models: how to uncouple them for tests and DB efficiency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, caching, model

I have the following models and associations:

```
SuccessCriterion
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :findings, through: :requirements

Requirement
  belongs_to :success_criterion
  has_many :findings

Finding
  belongs_to :requirement
  has_one :success_criterion, through: :requirement
```

- Each finding can have a status `critical`
- If a requirement has at least one critical finding, its status is critical, too
- And if a success criterion has at least one critical requirement, its status is critical, too

So the critical status is inherited.

When showing a list of success criteria, I want to show whether its status is critical or not. To do that, I calculate the status by iterating through all requirements and there again iterating through all findings and searching for at least one critical finding.

This takes a lot of DB queries, so I'm thinking about caching the status in the success criterion, and every time I'm adding/modifying/deleting a finding, the status should be updated in the success criterion.

What's the best way to do that? I thought about something like an `after_save` filter like this:

```
model Finding
  belongs_to :requirement
  has_one :success_criterion, through: :requirement

  after_save :update_success_criterion_status

  private
    def update_success_criterion_status
      if status.critical?
        success_criterion.update_attribute :status, :critical
      else
        success_criterion.calculate_status! # Iterate through all findings and look for at least one critical
      end
    end
end
```

In development, this would work well, I guess.

But what about testing? For unit testing the success criterion, I would have to provide the necessary associations for each and every single test, otherwise the `after_save` filter would crash. This means a lot of overhead for each test.

For sure, I could do something hacky like

```
after_save :update_success_criterion_status, unless: -> { Rails.env.test? }
```

but I don't think this is a good way.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I going completely the wrong route? Maybe there are even gems that handle stuff like this (modifying attributes of associated resources)?

**PS**

A similar requirement would be the possibility to counter cache a deeply associated element. Let's say, we have another model, e.g.

```
Project
  has_many :success_criteria
```

When we want to know how many findings there are in a project, we have to count them through both success criteria, requirements, and findings. A counter cache would save a lot of queries here, too. But there would need to be taken care of a lot of create/update/delete stuff of all the associated models to update the counter cache...

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? If not, would you mind commenting why not?

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive post. I couldn't take a look at it yet, but I definitely will soon.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to create another model that all associated models can efficiently look at. You can create a `Status` model with boolean columns for the different status types—at least one of them being the `critical` column, obviously—in which you store the count.

You will be able to retrieve any model's status with `<model_instance>.status` and with that, you can find out if it's critical or not. For example, `finding.status.critical?`, or `a_success_criterion.status.critical?` or even `a_success_criterion.critical?`.

```
model Finding
  belongs_to :requirement
  has_one :success_criterion, through: :requirement
  has_one :status

  def critical?
    status.critical? # Note: Rails should define this method for you on the status because it's a boolean column
  end
end
```

Similarly, to retrieve a `Requirements`'s status you would just do so with `requirement.status` and `requirement.critical?` to figure out if the requirement is critical or not.

```
model Requirements
  belongs_to :success_criterion
  has_many :findings
  has_many :statuses

  def critical?
    return true if statuses.where(critical: true).any?
  end
end
```

And to retrieve a `SuccessCriterion`'s status you would just do so with `success_criterion.status` because:

```
model SuccessCriterion
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :findings, through: :requirements
  has_many :statuses

  def critical?
    return true if statuses.where(critical: true).any?
  end
end
```

A **critical** part (no pun intended—initially:) is when you create a finding and therefore a status: you must or should give the status the ids of the the finding, requirement, and success criterion that it belongs to, so you might want to add a validation for their presence. Additionally, you might want to add a before_validation upon creating a status, either in `Status` or in `Finding`, which would look something like this (in `Status`):

```
model Status
  belongs_to :finding, :requirement, success_criterion
  before_validation :populate_ids
  validates_presence_of :finding_id, :requirement_id, :success_criterion_id

  def populate_ids
    self.finding_id = finding.id
    self.requirement_id = finding.requirement.try(:id)
    self.success_criterion_id = finding.requirement.try(:success_criterion).try(:id)
  end
end
```

In your tests, you just have to provide integers for the ids but they don't have to be of actual related models if you don't want to test for such relations—this is the beauty of it, aside from efficient querying :).

You get the general idea. I hope this helps!